# How do I diagnose a WiFi Error when the phone just reports "Unknown"?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, system-error, motorola-atrix-4g

I have a Motorola Atrix (MB860) running Android 2.3.6.  Just today the Wi-Fi suddenly stopped working; On the Quick Settings display it just shows "Unknown", on the phone's Wi-Fi Settings display it just shows "Error" and Wi-Fi won't turn on.

I've tried turning it off and back on several times, and I've tried pulling the battery twice.  I have installed Log Collector, but looking through the log I can't see anything even remotely relevant.

Talking to AT&T (God love 'em) on a previous Wi-Fi issue several months ago, they just blew me off and said they don't help with Wi-Fi issues, so I am not confident in getting help from that direction. If I have my phone replaced, my company will force me to get an iPhone due to a new Apple-only company policy.  So I am on my own.

How might I go about diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Try to search for Google the appropriate Kernel for 2.3.6 (presumably you are running on 4.5.141 firmware). Then flash it. When I say "flash", I mean a flash by CWM. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, that is my firmware version. What's "CWM"? I'm not sure about flashing it, it's a company phone.

Comment: Well, if that's company gadget, then I suggest you send it over for repair; let them do it for you. However, in case you wish to perform the flash, google "CWM flashing" and follow the tutorials. Good luck.