# How to Diagnose WiFi Issues?

Tags: wi-fi, logging, troubleshooting

My Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9515) with Android 5.0.1 does not connect to one particular WiFi any more - the [Eduroam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam) network at my workplace. The network is listed in the available networks list, with sufficient signal strength (3, mostly 4 (out of 4) bars), and with the small text *Saved, Secured* below. When I tap it, the popup menu *Connect* / *Modify* / *Forget* appears as usual. When I tap *Connect*, the popup menu closes and everything remains as it is. The network still shows *Saved, Secured*. In other words, **nothing at all happens**.

This happens *only* on this device (other devices, running Android* and other OSes, with exactly the same connection settings**, work well in this wifi network) and *only* with that network (I never have any issues connecting to other wifis with that problematic S4). Also, it used to connect to that network until about a week ago. To my knowledge, nothing significant (system update etc.) was changed to either the network or my device at that point.

*) an S4 (GT-I9505) with Android 4.2.2/4.3/4.4.2/5.0.1 (gradually updated while trying), a Google Nexus 7 with Android 5.1.1

**) TTLS, PAP, up-to-date certificate

I have removed and re-added the network, and switched off and on wifi several times, as suggested in numerous online resources (among others, by [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/25224/48610), or by [this troubleshooting guide](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-s/326698-guide-troubleshooting-wi-fi-connection-problems.html)). Also, I have re-checked and re-added my password and my user name several times.

Without knowing what I have to be searching for, here are some lines from the logcat around the time of trying to establish a connection that might be related:

> D/WifiMonitor(  883): didn't find BSSID Trying to associate with SSID 'eduroam'
>
> E/WifiStateMachine(  883): ConnectModeState SSID state=re-enabled nid=4 [id=4 ssid="eduroam"]
>
> E/WifiConfigStore(  883): SSID re-enabled for  "eduroam"CCKM had autoJoinStatus=0 self added false ephemeral false
>
> E/WifiStateMachine(  883): ConnectModeState SSID state=temp-disabled nid=4 [id=4 ssid="eduroam" auth_failures=2 duration=37]
>
> E/WifiConfigStore(  883): SSID temp disabled for  "eduroam"CCKM had autoJoinStatus=0 self added false ephemeral false
>
> E/WifiConfigStore(  883):  message=id=4 ssid="eduroam" auth_failures=2 duration=37

Unfortunately, I do not quite understand yet what they are saying, and whether they contain any information on the issue at all (other than the mere fact that the issue exists, as the connection failed to be established). It should be noted that many of the output messages seem to appear the same way in quite some PC Linux distributions, where quite a bit more options for debugging and reconfiguring the system are available than on an Android smartphone - therefore, the mentions of these messages I could find online in various forums were usually dead-ends for my particular case.

I cannot get any support by the organization running the wifi. The administrators say they have not heard of any such issues and solutions, and as they do not officially support Android devices, and everything works on their private devices, they will not actively search for a solution.

While I appreciate solutions, I understand that with the information provided it is hard, if not impossible, to solve the issue. Hence, my primary question is: **How do I *diagnose* what is wrong?** What do I have to look for in the logcat output? Are there any other places that I should look at?

There are some seemingly similar questions, which do not answer my question:

- [How to diagnose network connection issues?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104429/how-to-diagnose-network-connection-issues) - deals with mobile networks, not with wifi networks.
- [How to diagnose malfunctioning wifi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51373/how-to-diagnose-malfunctioning-wifi) - the [only answer to date](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51374/48610) specifically deals with modifying settings with respect to the specific issue of that question (which is different from mine). The general question from the title is not actually answered.
- [How do I diagnose a WiFi Error when the phone just reports “Unknown”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23783/how-do-i-diagnose-a-wifi-error-when-the-phone-just-reports-unknown) - it's about a different issue, and the [only answer so far](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/23788/48610) doesn't provide any general information for debugging.
- [wifi connection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56363/wifi-connection) - this is about the wifi feature as a whole remaining disabled.
- [Wifi Connection Problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82996/wifi-connection-problem) - frankly, after reading this question several times, I still do not understand what it is talking about. It says something about a laptop. It is most probably unrelated.
- [My Galaxy Nexus detects wifi signal(at home) but can't connect to it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25204/my-galaxy-nexus-detects-wifi-signalat-home-but-cant-connect-to-it) - this sounds fairly similar, however, I cannot follow some of the steps described in [the more elaborate answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/25224/48610), e.g. "Avoid poor connections option under Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Menu -> Advanced" does not seem to exist in my system version.

I can safely say that solutions such as [connecting a laptop to wifi first to wake up the DHCP server](http://www.stringcat.com/company_blog/2012/10/01/android-phone-not-connecting-to-wifi/) do not help here, as this is about an office building with 100+ laptops constantly connected to wifi already.

Comment: I recently had issues with my local University's eduroam network as well and AFAIK they did some changes to the certificate. Other eduroam networks across Europe worked fine. The issue is gone for me though. And I certainly didn't fix anything on my device

Comment: @stefan: Indeed, it works again now - but I'm still interested in an answer to this question. How can I diagnose this kind of issues?

Comment: that's interesting indeed.